# Swift get type from metatype

Tags: swift

If you have a swift meta type like `String.Type`. How do you go about transforming that to a class type, `String` in this case.

[See the docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html) 
- Metatype Type section

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to initialise an instance of a type from its metatype?

Comment: wasnt this question closed a few minutes ago as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks Dávid for taking the time. I don't need an instance, I could use the `init()` method for that, but rather the class. I need that so I can specify what type of objects I have in an array. good article related to this https://swiftrocks.com/whats-type-and-self-swift-metatypes.html

Comment: @Zsolt the only object that is of type `String.Type` is `String.self`. The only things of type `String` are string instances. What do you mean by saying that `String` is "a class type"? Please post some example pseudocode illustrating what you need.

Comment: thanks @Max. A use case: `NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")`. How do you go about doing that request if you only have `Entity.Type`.. but you need the class name.. `Entity`..

Comment: @Zsolt that question was already closed as a duplicate. You can get the class name using String interpolation, like `let class = Entity.Type; let className = "\(class)"`

Comment: `let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = class.fetchRequest()`

Comment: @DávidPásztor so based on your answer NSFetchRequest<"\(Entity.Type)">(entityName:"\(Entity.Type)") ?? it would work for the entity name.. but not for the `ResultType`, where I need the class itself. I know it has been closed due to someone not understanding what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's a great help.. it does work, but it does not solve my original question, it just uses `NSFetchRequestResult` instead of specifying the actual `Entity` there.. any idea how could that be done?

Comment: @Zsolt that's because your question is unclear. You need to clarify the exact problem you are trying to solve in the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an array of NSManagedObject.Type's

```
var entities: [NSManagedObject.Type] {
    return [Entity1.self,
            Entity2.self]
}

for entity in entities {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = entity.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        //do something with result
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
}
```

I tried a different version, you somehow need to check what you get back and handle each result individually so this is as good as I can get it. This compiles and executes fine.

```
func fetchOne<T: NSManagedObject>(_ objectType: T.Type) throws -> [T]? {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = objectType.fetchRequest()
    return try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [T]
}

func doFetchAll() {
    for entity in entities {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = entity.fetchRequest()
        do {
            if let result = try fetchOne(entity) {
                if result is [InstrumentData] {
                    print(result[0].value(forKey: "name"))
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is great, but if you need to know what type of objects you have in the `result`, you need to specify the object types, like `Entity1` or `Entity2`.. is there a  way to do that, if you only have the `Entity1.Type`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `result` array will be of type `[Entity1]` by default

Comment: @JoakimDanielson definitely not. You will need to use conditional binding to test at runtime if result is `Entity1` or `Entity2`. This will only compile because it turns everything into generic `NSManagedObject`s so you lose all other type info

Comment: @Max Right, I was thinking about `NSFetchRequest<Entity1> = Enity1.fetchRequest()`

Comment: @Max it will not loose _all_ type info, the right fetch request will be executed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "it" being the compiler. Only the dynamic type is retained, which the runtime has access to

Comment: @Zsolt update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't go from a metatype to a type.

Because Swift is statically typed, there are really only two situations you can be in. Either:

1. The compiler knows what type you have the metatype of, in which case you have the type already and don't need to use the metatype.
2. The compiler does not know what type you have the metatype of, in which case there is *no way* to get the type other than checking at runtime (which could fail)

Case 1 looks like this.

```
let x = "foo"                 // inferred as String
let y = type(of: x)           // inferred as String.Type
let z: [String] = [y.init()]  // inferred as [String], so types match
```

The compiler knows what the types are, and so do you. There's no need to go back from `y` to `String` because you can just type `String` directly and the compiler knows what's up.

Case 2 is like this.

```
class Base { required init() {} }
class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}

// compiler still knows all the types
let types = [A.self, B.self]

for type in types {
    // now all bets are off, everything is just Base
    switch type.init() {
    case let a as A:
        print(a)
    case let b as B:
        print(b)
    default: // you might end up here!
        print("no idea what it is")
    }
}
```

again, we can't go from `type` to `A` or `B` because the compiler has no idea what the types are anymore. You just have to test at runtime.